Building a Peltier module mini-cooler
I am just a noobie in engineering stuff.

Should the DC Fan 1 suck the air out of the Al heat sink OR push air into it for more
efficient heat dissipation?
For the small heat sink placed on the colder side of the peltier device, should I allow
atmospheric air to vent through point A or point B ? or BOTH ? or it doesnt matter ?
Any changes/suggestions are most welcome

This will be placed inclined at some angle on a study table so that it gives the cold air on the face.
I know it is inefficient in terms of power consumption but electricity is not a problem.



Hmm... would a swampcooler work better though?

I'd advise forgetting about things like aerodynamics for a moment, and consider the effects on the user.
With the design as you've shown it, the hot air from fan 1 is going to flow along the table top, so while the user is getting a cool breeze in the face, they're also getting a hot blast at their body (somewhere on the chest, depending on the height of the table).
I'd reverse the flow of hot air, so it's flowing as close to straight away from the user as possible.

